# AngularJs how to reload a template page after selecting a charater

Tags: angularjs

I am using http.get and i need to reload a template after selecting a character so that my template gives the answer according to what I selected

The code of the template

```
<div class="container-fluid" ng-controller="CriterioCtrl">

    <div id="result"></div>

    <div>
        Selected Items:
        <div ng-repeat="id in selection">
            {{id}}
        </div>        
    </div>

    <div ng-repeat-start="crit in data" class="row">
        <h2 align="center">{{crit.name}}</h2>

        <div ng-repeat="caracter in crit.characters" class="col-md-4">
            <div type="checkbox" value="{{caracter.id}}" ng-checked="selection.indexOf(caracter.id) > -1" ng-click="clickSelection(caracter.id)">
                <a href="#crit" class="thumbnail" ng-click="clickCriterios(caracter.id)">
                    <h4 align="center">{{caracter.name}}</h4>
                    <img ng-src="http://skaphandrus.com/{{caracter.image_url}}"/>
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>

    <div ng-repeat-end>
    </div>


<!--<button class="btn" ng-click="toggle()">Toggle</button>
<p ng-show="visible">Hello World!</p> codigo de um botao -->

</div>
```

This code is for the selection

```
$scope.selection=[];

$scope.clickSelection = function clickSelection(caracterId) {
    var idx = $scope.selection.indexOf(caracterId);
    // is currently selected
    if (idx > -1) {
        $scope.selection.splice(idx, 1);
    }   
    // is newly selected
    else {
        $scope.selection.push(caracterId);
    }
    var selectedId = $scope.selection;  
    console.log(selectedId);
    // Check browser support
    if (typeof(Storage) != "undefined") {
        // Store
        localStorage.setItem("idSelect", selectedId);
        // Retrieve
        document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = localStorage.getItem("idSelect");
    }
};
```

This code is the http part in another controller

```
MyApp.controller('EspeciesCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {

    $http({
        url: 'someurl', 
        method: "post",
        params: {module_id: localStorage.getItem("idMod"),"characters[]": [localStorage.getItem("idSelect")]}
    })
    .then(function(res){
        $scope.data = res.data;
    });
});
```

This is the code of the template that have to change after the selection

```
<div class="container-fluid" ng-controller="EspeciesCtrl">

    <div class="row">
        <div ng-repeat="esp in data" class="col-md-6">
            <a href="#infEsp" class="thumbnail" ng-click="clickEspecie(esp.id)">
                <h4 align="center">{{esp.name}}</h4>
                <img ng-src="{{esp.image_src}}"/>
            </a> 
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

How can i do that?

Comment: You should never really need to set the innerHTML in angular. That's what the data binding is for.

Comment: i know but that is only for testing in the end that will not be show up

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**edit 1**

If I've correctly understood, you may need to use `ng-show` (https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngShow) whose boolean value checks if the user selected anything and show the extra bit of code you need, instead of trying to have another http request.

Also, it seems like you are using `$scope.data` for both the `esp` and the `crit`, so you will end up with the errors.

---

You probably don't need to reload the template.
You may want to use the data in `$scope.data` inside the template in order to let Angular manage the update on the view. As soon as the $scope.data changes, the rendered HTML changes too.

I can't comment but it would be helpful if you could share the template you are using and be more specific in your request :)

Comment: i have updated the code if you have something new to add please

Comment: another question how can i pass a array to the params of the http?

Comment: I'm using two controllers with the $scope.data so i don't have any error there, and thanks for the help i will try to use what you recomend if I have any doubt I will ask you. @datamosh

Comment: Sure, no worries, glad I gave you hitnt!

Comment: can you give me your email or facebook page so i can talk to you in a more private way, if you do not mind @datamosh